# Manually mock node module when root with a customized root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm mocking a node module using `createMockFromModule` following the [manual mock documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), here's what the website says:

> If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: `lodash`), the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory adjacent to `node_modules` (unless you configured `roots` to point to a folder other than the project root) and will be **automatically** mocked. There's no need to explicitly call `jest.mock('module_name')`.

However, my root points to a folder and the website doesn't specify where to put the mocks for this situation. Does anyone know?